# Calculating row-level ratios in a table view

Tags: tableau

I am trying to get the fulfillment ratio by Destination Distribution Entity

Fulfillment Status is a property on a record called a 'directive'

I have no idea how to do this, any help is very appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I can go to **Analysis > Percentage of > Row in Pane**

and it will calculate the percentages of each cell in the table

But now I have a new question, which is if it is possible
also show the counts and if it is possible to get subtotals and grandtotals as well if you are doing a Percentage Of Calculation